# Can't boot Ubuntu on Win10 / Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Dual Boot

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

First of all, I'm sorry for asking this question, because obviously this is a problem for a lot of people, but after trying all provided solutions I've seen without any success, I hope to get some answers by asking this question here.

I've got an HP Pavillion 11 x360 laptop, with Windows 8 pre-installed on it. At some point I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS alongside Windows, which at a later point I updated to Windows 10. This actually worked fine for me, with the GRUB manager loading by default at start-up; I was able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows, like I wanted it to be. I experienced some minor problems, though, and I thought I could resolve those by a clean reinstallation of both Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

I followed the instructions from the official website and this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi), and installed first Windows 10 x64, after that Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64 bit as well), both with a USB installation medium. I installed Windows in EFI mode (I checked by looking at the setupact.log).

This didn't work for me, because the GRUB manager doesn't appear on start-up, and Ubuntu doesn't appear in the BIOS boot options, while Windows is booting by default. The only way I can boot Ubuntu in the first place is by using the USB installation medium, closing the GRUB manager, and then I get the BIOS option to boot the already installed Ubuntu.

I tried some things:

- Disabled both Fast & Secure Boot
- "bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi" on Windows, but it didn't change anything
- Tried the boot-repair (http://paste.ubuntu.com/25766399/)
- Used the grub-customizer, without any success
- Changed the boot-order manually from within Ubuntu, with no effects
- Tried installing GRUB on the main partition, but got an error

I'm reluctant to try and reinstall everything, because I've used Windows on the laptop for some time now and I don't know what I would do differently next time, but if you guys say it's the best course of action, I will do it of course. If someone could help me out here, I'd be really grateful. I'm sure I messed up at some point and probably would have gotten the result I want if I had done everything correctly, but I've tried the steps mentioned above again and wasn't successful.

Thanks in advance for any kind of helpful answer! I hope I could express myself properly, please note that English is not my native language.

Comment: are you sure that ubuntu installed in EFI mode? and that you used the EFI partition on the HDD not the USB?

Comment: Report shows both Windows & Ubuntu installed in UEFI boot mode. From HP's UEFI boot menu can you boot Ubuntu entry? HP - escape + F9 for boot menu, F10 for bios setup Does Internal Hard Disk entry boot Ubuntu as Boot-Repair copies shimx64.efi to bootx64.efi as fallback or hard drive boot entry.

Comment: Thank you both for your fast & helpful response! This is embarassing for me: by pressing F9 during start-up I could actually boot Ubuntu and access the GRUB. I've always tried to do this by pressing F10, where Ubuntu doesn't show up as an entry when changing the boot order. My problem is mainly solved by this, thank you very much! One problem remains though: how can I set Ubuntu to boot by default? I can't change the boot order in the F9 menu, it seems.